# PlayScalaJS with bootstrap not working

Tags: scala, playframework, scala.js, playscalajs

I recently came across the fact that the imports of bootstrap were not accessible in my code. Namely, the plugin alert for jQuery was not available within my code (`jQuery.fn.alert` was undefined). I had in the header:

```
<script src="@routes.Assets.at("lib/jquery/jquery.min.js")" 
  type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="@routes.Assets.at("lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js")" 
  type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and in the body:

```
<body>
    @playscalajs.html.scripts("client")
</body>
```

In the client script, when it called `$("...").alert()`, I receive the **error**: `alert is not a function`, although I verified bootstrap did define it.

How to make bootstrap and playscalajs work nicely together?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem came from `@playscalajs.html.scripts("client")` which is unfold to these:

```
<script src="/assets/client-jsdeps.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/client-fastopt.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/client-launcher.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

`jQuery` is imported again in `client-jsdeps.js` since it is a scala-js dependency. Since I could not interleave bootstrap imports before the `client-launcher.js` script and after the `client-jsdeps.js` scripts, I delayed the execution of the main object using the following code:

```
// New object calling the previous Main object
@JSExport
object MainDelayed extends js.JSApp { 
  @JSExport def main(): Unit = $(document).ready(Main.main _)
}

// The original object
object Main { 
  def main() = { ... }
}
```